# nginx ingress returning 404 for react application, but document returned

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

We are using nginx ingress in our Kubernetes cluster to serve up some services as well as nginx as a base layer for our containerized React applications. We deployed the react applications and nginx ingress is routing to the react applications and serving them. We can see the react application just fine in our browsers. However, if we look at the network traffic in the browser's developer tools, we see that the initial load of the web page from the container yields a 404 status even though the file is actually returned and displayed in the browser. I suspect our nginx.conf file is incorrect and we're getting the application because it's also configured as the 404 handler.

Here is our nginx.conf file that we copy into the container that serves up the react app:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;

        # support for router correct?
        try_files $uri /index.html;

        error_page 404 /index.html;
        location = / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            internal;
        }
    }
}
```

What do we need to do to get nginx to return a 200 instead of a 404 with our application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refresh the page or access a specific route directly, nginx is trying to find a file corresponding to that route on the server, which doesn't exist since React applications are typically single-page applications (SPAs) where all routes are handled client-side. The 404 status is likely being returned because of the try_files directive. When a request is made to a non-existent file, Nginx is attempting to serve /index.html, which exists, but it's also triggering a 404 status since the original requested file doesn't exist. However, because of the error_page 404 /index.html directive, Nginx is then serving /index.html for any 404 error, which is why you're still seeing your application despite the 404 status. You can simply remove the try_files directive and rely solely on the index directive to serve the index.html file for any request. 
You could try moving root directive outside of the location block to define the root directory for all requests.The location / block could use try_files to attempt to serve the requested file, and if it doesn't exist, it could serve /index.html, effectively routing all requests to your React application's entry point. Perhaps try something like this?

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.html;

    location = /index.html {
        internal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nazrul, I used a simpler form that ended up working. Do you see any issues with this?
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}

Comment: looks good to me.